# alter primary key and all references in sql server

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I'm trying to alter a primary key field but is being referenced by about 93 tables.

I used the following script to drop and create the FK constraints: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2958.script-to-create-all-foreign-keys.aspx

but I still need to alter all those referenced fields and they seem to reference others.

Anyone know an script that can handle all of that or knows a tool that can help me achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "they seem to reference others" - this is not clear to me. Please explain more clearly & add whatever error message you see, exactly as it is displayed.

Comment: Floor code is a primary key with building code in the floor table. There are about 93 tables that reference floor code. Room table for example has Building Code, Floor Code and Room Code as primary key and Building and Floor are also foreign keys. There are several others that also have that 3 part foreign keys, like employee, lease, etc. So trying to alter the size of the Floor Code has been giving me grief. There are FK constraints for all of them. Trying to use SSMS is give me a message I can't do that update without dropping the table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put all details in your question (you can edit it), not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSMS table designer will generate this script for you.  Just make the change in the designer and generate the change script.

[image]

There's a a safety config you have to set before the designer will generate scripts that drop and recreate tables.  That should be done on production servers only after testing.

[image]

Comment: I tried that and I get an message Saving Changes is not permitted, The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and recreated.

Comment: See update to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did exactly the changes I needed.